# Scroll cuando aparece el teclado

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uitableview

Tengo una duda a cerca de cómo manejar cuando sale el teclado en una aplicación iOS.

Resulta que en Spotify en el iPhone cuando te vas a registrar, seleccionas un campo y sale el teclado. Quedando tapado el botón de registro. Ellos lo han solucionado haciendo que se pueda hacer scroll sobre la vista y así llegar al botón.

Mi duda es la siguiente: ¿Lo han solucionado con una `TableView`? ¿O hay alguna forma de conseguir ese efecto sin usar la `TableView`?

Recuerdo que no busco subir la vista cuando salga el teclado. Quiero lo de hacer scroll.

Comment: Pues lo que tienes que hacer es poner un scrollview y dentro de ese scrollview pones el textfield.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Spidvmp pero eso ya lo se. No te preocupes, borro la pregunta. Ya la he solucionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi me ha funcionado usar esta librería https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Siempre muestra el textfield haciendo un tipo scroll, si tienes asignado algo en la propiedad PlaceHolder también lo muestra en el teclado y se puede personalizar los botones de siguiente, anterior y ocultar teclado.

Answer (score 3):

Sencillo , cuando tenemos un scrollView o bien un tableView hay una opción de keyboard que generalmente esta como : **do not dismiss** , cambia esta opción a dismiss interactly o dismiss on drag y se te ocultara el teclado al hacer scroll o tocar el scroll .
Otra opción es aplicar un gesture a la view y que active un metodo que oculte el teclado.

Comment: Si, bueno es una opción pero no me refería a ello. De todas formas ya resolví ese problema.